# Как создать уникальную ссылку на страницу в Angular 2?

Tags: angular2

Мне нужно сгенерировать уникальную ссылку, чтобы когда юзер перешел по ней, он оказывался на некой странице. Тем не менее, юзер не может напрямую перейти по ней, если будет просто вбивать URL адрес в адресной строке.

Зачем это нужно? Например, бета доступ к какому-то сайту. Юзер отправляет заявку, админ ему отправляет на почту уникальную ссылку, перейдя по которой, юзер оказывается на странице регистрации.

Насколько я понимаю, необходимо генерировать какой-то токен, передать его в саму ссылку как параметер, а потом делать проверку в компоненте.

Но как это реализовать во втором Angular? В частности, как передать токен как параметер?

Comment: Переход по ссылке с почты ничем не отличается от вбивания URL адреса в адресной строке

Comment: @vp_arth А что, если если ссылку нельзя придумать и она содержит случайные символы? Например вот так http://example.com/4273864832764832764832 ? В таком случае доступ к ссылке смогут получить только специальные пользователи.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код, как вы генерируете ссылку без токена. Обычно этим, как и отправкой письма, занимается сервер.

Comment: @vp_arth я согласен что это работа сервера, но у меня получается это таким образом, что клиенская сторона показывает страницы, а на API просто посылаются запросы.

Comment: @vp_arth хорошо. Представим, что я сгенерировал ссылку на сервере и отправил письмо с ней. Тогда вопрос заключается в том, как на клиенте проверять правильный ли токен, если изначально он был сгенерирован на сервере,

Comment: во первых переходя по ссылке вы попадаете на сервер. Если не хотите сделать там немножко динамики - значит токен отправляется на сервер чз ajax, в ответ присылается инфа об этом токене.

Comment: @vp_arth Насколько я понимаю, примерно так это дело должно выглядеть. У меня есть входные данные на клиенте, например email юзера. На сервере я шифрую этот email, делаю из него токен, формирую на его основе ссылку и отправляю на почту. Когда юзер переходит по ссылке, сервер производит проверку правильный ли токен. Но опять же непонятно как на клиенте сделать проверку: которая определит сможет ли юзер попасть на страницу.